# Ruby On Rails Active Storage purge/delete method throws NoMethodError

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a problem with my image purge/delete for images after they have been uploaded via Active Storage. I have tried to follow the instructions and I still get the same error. The error is described in command line as Template Error ::Error (undefined method 'stringify_keys' for ....

Any suggestion would be great

[image]

**Command Line**

```
ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method `stringify_keys' for "http://localhost:3000/jobs/21/delete_image_attachment":String):
    11:         <div class="panel-body">
    12:           <span class="pull-right">
    13:             <%=
    14:             link_to 'Remove', delete_image_attachment_job_url(@job.images[image]),
    15:             remote: true,
    16:             method: :delete,
    17:             data: {confirm: "Are you sure"} do %>

app/views/jobs/_photos_list.html.erb:14:in `block in _app_views_jobs__photos_list_html_erb__192211306_83310024'
app/views/jobs/_photos_list.html.erb:5:in `_app_views_jobs__photos_list_html_erb__192211306_83310024'
app/views/jobs/photo_upload.html.erb:51:in `_app_views_jobs_photo_upload_html_erb___795227943_83576688'
```

**My Model**

```
class Job < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  has_many_attached :images

  validates :job_category, presence: true
  validates :job_type, presence: true
  validates :recurrence, presence: true
  #validates :job_title, presence: true
  #validates :job_description, presence: true

end
```

**The Controller**

```
class JobsController < ApplicationController

  before_action :set_job , except: [:index, :new, :create, :edit]
  before_action :authenticate_user!, except: [:show]
  before_action :is_authorised, only: [:listing, :budget, :description, :photo_upload, :location, :update, :show, :delete ]

  def delete_image_attachment
    @images = ActiveStorage::Attachment.find(params[:id])
    @images.purge
    redirect_back(fallback_location: request.referer)
  end
```

**The View**

```
<% if @job.images.attached? %>
  <br/>

  <div class="row">
    <% (0...@job.images.count).each do |image| %>
    <div class="col-md-4">
      <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading preview">
          <%= image_tag(@job.images[image]) %>
        </div>
        <div class="panel-body">
          <span class="pull-right">
            <%=
            link_to 'Remove', delete_image_attachment_job_url(@job.images[image]),
            remote: true,
            method: :delete,
            data: {confirm: "Are you sure"} do %>
              <i class="fa fa-trash-o" aria-hidden="true"></i>
            <% end %>
          </span>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <% end %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

**My Routes**

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do

  root 'pages#home'

  resources :jobs_devs
  resources :jobs

  resources :jobs_devs, except: [:placeholder] do
    member do
      get 'listing'
      get 'budget'
      get 'description'
      get 'photo_upload'
      get 'featured'
      get 'location'
      get 'update'
      get 'premium'
      get 'show'
      delete :delete_image_attachment
    end
  end

  devise_for    :users,
            :path => '',
            :path_names => {:sign_in => 'login', :sign_out => 'logout', :edit => 'profile', :sign_up => 'registration'},
            :controllers => {:omniauth_callbacks => 'omniauth_callbacks', :registrations => 'registrations' }

  resources :users, only: [:show]
  resources :jobs, except: [:edit] do
    member do
      get 'listing'
      get 'budget'
      get 'description'
      get 'photo_upload'
      get 'featured'
      get 'location'
      get 'update'
      get 'premium'
      get 'show'
      delete :delete_image_attachment
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Can you please add your routes ?

Comment: routes added above

Comment: what do you get when you do rake routes for `delete_image_attachment`

Comment: Try with this `<%= link_to 'remove',  delete_image_attachment_job_url(image_id: image),  method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %>`

Also change in controller
`images` -> `image`
`params[:id]` -> `params[:image_id]`

Answer (score 0):

I think problem is in your image loop in view and routes

Some changes in view and iterate through `@job.images`

> This is without remote: true

```
<% if @job.images.attached? %>
  <br/>

  <div class="row">
    <% @job.images.each do |image| %>
    <div class="col-md-4">
      <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading preview">
          <%= image_tag(image) %>
        </div>
        <div class="panel-body">
          <span class="pull-right">
            <%=
            link_to 'Remove', delete_image_attachment_job_url(image_id: image)
            method: :delete,
            data: {confirm: "Are you sure"} do %>
              <i class="fa fa-trash-o" aria-hidden="true"></i>
            <% end %>
          </span>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <% end %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Controller

```
  def delete_image_attachment
    @image = ActiveStorage::Attachment.find(params[:image_id])
    @image.purge
    redirect_back(fallback_location: request.referer)
  end
```

Comment: No luck with this solution. I get a NoMethodError in Jobs#photoupload. Error is at line 13 ...link_to 'Remove', delete_image_attachment_job_url(image_id: image)

Comment: Please add `photoupload` method and its view

Comment: I have added additional info to your answer

Comment: Please add this info in your question

Answer (score 0):

Because you are using the block form of `link_to` you should put the text between do/end:

```
        <%=
        link_to delete_image_attachment_job_url(@job.images[image]),
        remote: true,
        method: :delete,
        data: {confirm: "Are you sure"} do %>
          <i class="fa fa-trash-o" aria-hidden="true">Remove</i>
        <% end %>
```

Like in the example from [docs](https://api.rubyonrails.org/v5.2.2/classes/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper.html#method-i-link_to):

> You can use a block as well if your link target is hard to fit into the name parameter. ERB example:

```
<%= link_to(@profile) do %>
  <strong><%= @profile.name %></strong> -- <span>Check it out!</span>
<% end %>
# => <a href="/profiles/1">
       <strong>David</strong> -- <span>Check it out!</span>
     </a>
```